# Update DataSet Schema On Crystal Reports for VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I'm creating a report using the built-in module of Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2008, and for that I have added a DataSet containing multiple DataTables.
As for now, the DataTables have a certain quantity of fields which may grow in the future, so the next person updating my report will need to update the DataSet schema.

The problem is that whenever I add new fields to a Datatable, that Datatable's fields isn't updated in Crystal Reports.
Every time I tried doing this I was forced to remove the DataSet completely and add it again in order to have the updated schema, which is a very bad solution because all fields already on the reports get lost.

Is there a simple way to make it update the structure? (I've already clicked Verify Database under database Expert).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After having a conversation with a friend, we both figured out how to overcome this problem but the solution is not very elegant:

1. Add columns to your `DataTable`
2. Close Visual Studio
3. re-open Visual Studio
4. right click the `DataTable` to update
5. click `Set Datasource Location`
6. add your `DataSet` connection again and update your `DataTable`
   against the one present in the new connection

Note: if you try to update again, you must close visual studio again and repeat everything.

Hope this can help someone with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for finding the solution. It was getting difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Similar sort of issue using models (c# classes) in MVC.  It's very opaque but essentially if you create another database location for another model, you can set the report to that second model/class, then set it back to the original, and at that point it finally pulls in the new fields in your model.