# crystal reports verify database does not update database fields

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a .xsd file that got updated (added a column to a datatable in the dataset).
I tried to verify the database in the .rpt file but the new column did not get loaded under the database fields and it is telling me that the database is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please close and reopen the visual studio. It may be cache problem. Just change any field position and save. Also at database level just add parameter or change datatype, re-verify it and revert again to show is this every thing sync.

For more detail check the links.

[Update DataSet Schema On Crystal Reports for VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959814/update-dataset-schema-on-crystal-reports-for-vs2008)

http://rikardalard.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/updating-a-crystal-report-if-changing-the-xsd-data-source/

[Adding a column to a DataSet (xsd) for a Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575169/adding-a-column-to-a-dataset-xsd-for-a-crystal-report)